# redirect http non www and remove /index.html in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've tried to redirect with various combination but still no luck

From

```
http://example.com/article/index.html
http://example.com/category/news/index.html
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/article.html
https://www.example.com/category/news.html
```

Comment: The rewrite rule is quite straight forward (e.g. `rewrite ^(/.+)/index(\.html)$ https://www.example.com$1$2 permanent;`). What have you tried and what was the results of your tests?

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you. It's very useful.